# How FastCGI will improve the performance of my php application?

Tags: fastcgi, typo3

How fastCGI will improve PHP performance, is it recommended to use for my typo3 CMS. Will it produce any side effects.?

Comment: While dated, [a quick visit to the site will explain the rational for FastCGI and how it can improve performance](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/6?q=node/15) (vs. normal CGI). "mod_php" is another tool that can help performance. Of course, if "normal CGI" runs just fine -- then let it ride ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TYPO3 runs fine with FastCGI - if your server is configured correctly, you will not run into trouble.

Answer (score 2):

I run PHP through fastCGI for more than 5 years now, having multiple Typo3 instances running on it. I did this out of the fact that normal CGI cluttered up my servers with that many instances. FastCGI now handles them without any problems.

Of course mod_php might be the fastest of all solutions. Yet you lose some flexibility like being able to configure each host separably or running different versions of PHP within the same LAMP stack, which is quite some advantage in days of PHP 5.2 to PHP 5.3 incompatibilities.

I have no numbers to offer here, but at least some exeperience. My suggestion, go for fastCGI if you feel confident about setting it up. Its worth it. Or try mod_php if you use Apache and don't care so much about the flexibility CGI would give you. Its very easy to setup as well.

cu
Roman